# Unable to add items to class Array

Tags: arrays, swift2

I am fetching data from JSON, and store inside in an NSArray. I've verified that I've successfully grab the data from JSON. The grabbed data will be stored into strings, then added into class array.  However I get an error: "Thread: 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

```
var personList = [PersonTable]()
do {
    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
    let resultArray = resultJSON as? NSArray
    for jsonObjectString in resultArray! {
      let name = jsonObjectString["Name"] as! String
      let code = jsonObjectString["Code"] as! String
      let description = jsonObjectString["Description"] as! String
      self.personList[count].addPerson(Name, code: code, description: description)
      count++
    }
```

This is my class array in a separate swift file.

```
func addPerson(name: String, code: String, description: String){
    self.name = name
    self.code = code
    self.description = description
}
```

Comment: what type is `personList`? Please add the code how `personList` is declared

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added.

Comment: is `addPerson` a method in class `PersonTable`?

Comment: If `count` is the number of elements in `self.personList`, then this will blow: `self.personList[count]`.

Comment: @vadian Yes addPerson is a method in the PersonTable class. As shown on my code screen.

Comment: @trojanfoe count starts at 0 during runtime. However I also suspected if it could be that issue. So I to change count to 0, but same error.

Comment: You cannot access an element of an array that does not exist.  If you are adding to an array then call its `append()` method.

Comment: `addPerson` is a instance method not a class method which assigns values to properties. Where is the instance created where the properties belong to? I don't understand your model design.

Comment: may be stupid question. Where is your catch block ? and what about personList[count].addPerson ??????

Comment: @vadian Sorry vadian, I'm very new to swift and I don't quite get what you meant. Trying to interpret what you meant, are you asking where is my init to store the strings instead? Where I should not be creating a method to do this?